# How user access should be validated in Api with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I have a API with 3 layers:

1. Admin Controller and EditorViewerController
2. Manager - which maps controller's DTO to a database model
3. Repository - which puts data in the database

In my API I have controller which creates entity `A`. Users can create a `A` and they become an owner of this resource. They also can invite other users to be a part of `A` (its giving them a corresponding role) as `Editor` or `Viewer`.
In database there are 3 tables:

1. `As`
2. `AEditors`
3. `AViewers`

When user wants to edit `A` I'm validating if this user is an `Owner`, `Editor` or `Viewer`. In `Viewer` case I'm returning `403 Forbidden`. Basically this validation checks if `UserId` is tied to `AId` in `AEditors` table.

For now flow is:

1. Endpoint calls Manager which calls Repository and passes mapped request to db model
2. In Repository I'm getting existing `A` entity with included `AEditors` table and then checking if `A.Editors` have my `UserId`, if he is `Editor` or `Owner` the entity is updated.

BUT then I implemented some `Admin` account and endpoints in separate controller. `Admin` should be able to edit all `A` without even checking for its permissions, which got me thinking that this validation should be done on Controller level, cause for now implemented validation on Repository level will throw access denied for `Admin`.

I'm wondering if this is correct what I have for now and should I just create some exception from validation if user is `Admin` or if I should validate a user in `AController` and `AdminController` instead by creating some static method in Repository so it would be line included in the endpoint method where I want to validate.

```
ARepository.ValidateUserIsEditor(_dbContext, aId, userId);
```

So if user will be `Viewer` it will return `Forbidden` just before calling a manager, mapping DTO and calling Repository for existing `A` with included `AEditors` table. But if user will be `Editor` then 3 queries will be send to a database. One for validating, second for geting existing resource (but without including `AEditors`) and then the last one updating the `A`.

Which approach would you recommend?

Comment: In my opinion, You can write a custom Authorization policy, After user logged in  and access this endpoint, your custom Authorization policy will determine if the current user can access this endpoint. In this case, if the role of user is `Viewer`, he even can't access into this endpoint.

Comment: I was also thinking about it but then I would need to create a Claim for every resource a user is in, would need to manage it on every creation/deletion/role change

Comment: indeed, Create a specified controller for admin is also a very common method.